# Nvidia - xrandr crashes with Caught signal 11

Tags: xorg, nvidia, xrandr, gpu

First I've plugged in the external GPU (Nvidia GTX1070) into my Lenovo X220
(pci express) and was immediately able to get the external screen working.
Nouveau drivers were apparently already installed.

However I wasn't able to
select a GPU for rendering blender.

Thus I Installed these packages:

```
pacman -S nvidia cuda nvidia-settings
```

Now executing:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1-0 --auto
```

results in crashing Xorg with this */var/log/Xorg.0.log* excerpt:

```
[   420.585] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   421.571] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 3840x2160
[   421.645] randr: falling back to unsynchronized pixmap sharing
[   421.645] (EE) 
[   421.645] (EE) Backtrace:
[   421.645] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x53) [0x558b15250a53]
[   421.645] (EE) 1: /usr/lib/Xorg (0x558b1510a000+0x151895) [0x558b1525b895]
[   421.645] (EE) 2: /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x7f5eed609000+0x3c3e0) [0x7f5eed6453e0]
[   421.645] (EE) 
[   421.645] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[   421.645] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   421.645] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[   421.645] (EE) 
[   421.645] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
at http://wiki.x.org
for help. 
[   421.645] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   421.645] (EE) 
[   421.645] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[   421.704] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

What can I do?

Comment: nouveau does not support CUDA at all. https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

Comment: Thank you. Hence "Thus I Installed these packages..". Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem an I put here the solution I found, because it can help someone.

It seems to be a problem with the Intel driver.

The solution (in my case) was adding to the `xorg.conf` file, under the Section `Device` this line:

```
Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
```

At least, my problem was solved in this way.

I got this information here:
[Intel Graphics - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics_(Espa%C3%B1ol)#AccelMethod)